# Outlook view changed in main inbox folder but not others

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Outlook changed the view of the inbox to what I think of as the classic view.

[image: classic view]

I usually have it set to this view

[image: three panel layout]

It seems to have changed all by itself. All my other folders are in the normal view (second picture) as I intend them to be. In the view settings none of the views seem to change it back to the normal view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is enabling the "Reading Pane", and in your other view, it's on the right. Open the "View" ribbon and go to the "Layout" section, click "Reading Pane", and select "Right".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to cscracker's suggestion, it's also possible that you are in the "Preview" view instead of the default "Compact" view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue and neither of the above suggestions solved it. What worked for me was selecting Compact under Change View and then clicking Reset View.

[image]